# R function stops running with no visible errors

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I've written a custom function to read in a JSON file and extract all of the relevant info that I need, with the goal of running it over all files in a directory. I've created a character vector of all the files and using sapply/lapply, I've been able to run the function like below.

```
setwd("/directory/")
file.list=dir()
sapply(file.list,function)
```

For some reason during execution, it reaches a point where it outputs the following and stops for no reason, shown below. I have warnings suppressed, and the only warnings that I've been getting are ones that I expect. Running the parser individually on all the failing files works, giving me the table I want to see.

```
#expected output
#expected output

$'filename'
[1]FALSE
$'filename'
[1]NULL
```

I've attached my parser here if it helps, I'm sure it's not optimized and there's better ways to do it, but speed is not a primary concern here. Thanks in advance!

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

trialParse=function(filename){
  options(warn=-1)
  options(max.print=99999)
  parsefile=read_json(filename)
  title=str_remove(basename(filename),".json")
  #cat(sprintf("Schema Version is %s\n", parsefile$metadata$schemaVersion))
    if (parsefile$report$workflow$reportType!="DNA"){
      #cat(sprintf("%s report is not DNA, moved\n",title))
      from=paste("~/JSON_parsing/workingFiles/",title,".json",sep='')
      to=paste("~/JSON_parsing/failedFiles/",title,".json",sep='')
      file.rename(from=from,to=to)
    }else{
      #cat(sprintf("%s\n",title))
      
      #Extract report info
      if (exists("report",parsefile)&&length(parsefile$report)!=0){
        reportData=rbindlist(list(parsefile$report,parsefile$report$workflow),fill=TRUE)
        reportData$workflow=NULL
        reportData[is.na(reportData)]=""
        reportData=reportData%>%
          unique()%>%
          summarize_all(funs(trimws(paste(.,collapse=''))))
        #assign(paste("reportData_",title,sep=''),reportData,envir=.GlobalEnv)
      }else{
        print("No report info")
      }
      
      #Extract patient info  
      if(exists("patient",parsefile)&&length(parsefile$patient)!=0){
        patientData=as.data.frame(t(unlist(parsefile$patient)))
        #assign(paste("patientData_",title,sep=''),patientData,envir=.GlobalEnv)
      }else{
        print("No patient info")
      }
      
      #Extract order info
      if(exists("report",parsefile)&&length(parsefile$report)!=0){
        orderData=rbindlist(list(parsefile$order,parsefile$order$test),fill=TRUE)
        orderData$test=NULL
        orderData[is.na(orderData)]=""
        orderData=orderData%>%
          unique()%>%
          summarize_all(funs(trimws(paste(.,collapse=''))))
        #assign(paste("orderData_",title,sep=''),orderData,envir=.GlobalEnv)
      }else{
        print("No order info")
      }
      
      #Extract specimens info
      if(exists("specimens",parsefile)&&length(parsefile$specimens)!=0){
        specimens=list()
        for(i in 1:length(parsefile$specimens)){
          specimens[[i]]=as.data.frame(t(unlist(parsefile$specimens[[i]])))
        }
        specimensData=do.call(rbind.fill,specimens)%>%
          unique()
        #assign(paste("specimensData_",title,sep=''),specimensData,envir=.GlobalEnv)
      }else{
        print("No specimens info")
      }
      
      #Extract   mutations info
      if (exists("results",parsefile)&&length(parsefile$results)!=0){
        #Tumor Mutational Burden
        if (length(parsefile$results$tumorMutationalBurden!=0)){
          tmbdata=as.data.frame(t(unlist(c(parsefile$results[1],parsefile$results[2],parsefile$results[3]))))
          #assign(paste("tmbData_",title,sep=''),tmbdata,envir=.GlobalEnv)
        }
        #Somatic Potentially Actionable Mutations
        if (exists("somaticPotentiallyActionableMutations",parsefile$results)&&length(parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableMutations)!=0){
          #Remove Therapies
          for (i in 1:length(parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableMutations)){
            for (j in 1:length(parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableMutations[[i]]$variants)){
              parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableMutations[[i]]$variants[[j]]$therapies=NULL
              }
            }
          mutations=list()
          variants=list()
          #Extract Somatic Potentially Actionable Mutations data
            #Per Entry
          for(i in 1:length(parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableMutations)){
              #Per Variants in Entry
            for(j in 1:length(parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableMutations[[i]]$variants)){
              variants[[j]]=rbindlist(list(parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableMutations[[i]]$variants[j],parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableMutations[[i]]$variants[[j]]),fill=TRUE)
            }
              #Per Variants in Entry
            for (j in 1:length(variants)){
              variantsData=do.call(rbind,variants[j])
              mutationsList=parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableMutations[[i]]
              mutationsList$variants=NULL
              mutationTable=rbindlist(list(mutationsList,variantsData),fill=TRUE)
              mutations=append(mutations,list(rbindlist(list(mutationsList,variantsData),fill=TRUE)))
            }
          }
          #Build SPAMS table
          SPAMsData=do.call(rbind,mutations)
          SPAMsData$mutationEffect=NULL
          SPAMsData=SPAMsData%>%
            unique()%>%
            fill(c(1:4),.direction=c("down"))%>%
            fill(c(5:ncol(SPAMsData)),.direction=c("up"))%>%
            unique()%>%
            mutate(mutation_type="Somatic Potentially Actionable Mutation")
        }else{
          print("No SPAMS")
        }
        
        #Somatic Potentially Actionable Copy Number Variants
        if (exists("somaticPotentiallyActionableCopyNumberVariants",parsefile$results)&&length(parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableCopyNumberVariants)!=0){
          #Remove Therapies
          for (i in 1:length(parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableCopyNumberVariants)){
            parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableCopyNumberVariants[[i]]$therapies=NULL
          } 
          #Extract Somatic Potentially Actionable Copy Number Variants Data
          variants=list()
          for(i in 1:length(parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableCopyNumberVariants)){
            variants[[i]]=as.data.frame(t(unlist(parsefile$results$somaticPotentiallyActionableCopyNumberVariants[[i]])))
          }
          SPACNVsData=do.call(rbind,variants)%>%
            mutate(mutation_type="Somatic Potentially Actionable Copy Number Variants")
          rm(variants)
        }else{
          print("No SPACNVs")
        }
        
        #Somatic Biologically Relevant Variants
        if (exists("somaticBiologicallyRelevantVariants",parsefile$results)&&length(parsefile$results$somaticBiologicallyRelevantVariants)!=0){
          #Extract Data
          variants=list()
          for(i in 1:length(parsefile$results$somaticBiologicallyRelevantVariants)){
            variants[[i]]=as.data.frame(t(unlist(parsefile$results$somaticBiologicallyRelevantVariants[[i]])))
          }
          SBRVsData=do.call(rbind,variants)%>%
            mutate(mutation_type="Somatic Biologically Relevant Variants")
          rm(variants)
        }else{
          print("No SBRVs")
        }
        
        #Somatic Variants of Unknown Significance
        if (exists("somaticVariantsOfUnknownSignificance",parsefile$results)&&length(parsefile$results$somaticVariantsOfUnknownSignificance)!=0){
          #Extract Data
          variants=list()
          for(i in 1:length(parsefile$results$somaticVariantsOfUnknownSignificance)){
            variants[[i]]=as.data.frame(t(unlist(parsefile$results$somaticVariantsOfUnknownSignificance[[i]])))
          }
          SVUSsData=do.call(rbind,variants)%>%
            mutate(mutation_type="Somatic Variants of Unknown Significance")
          rm(variants)
        }else{
          print("No SVUSs")
        }
        
        #Fusion Variants
        if (exists("fusionVariants",parsefile$results)&&length(parsefile$results$fusionVariants)!=0){
          #Remove Therapies
          for (i in 1:length(parsefile$results$fusionVariants)){
            parsefile$results$fusionVariants[[i]]$therapies=NULL
          }
          #Extract Data
          variants=list()
          for(i in 1:length(parsefile$results$fusionVariants)){
            variants[[i]]=as.data.frame(t(unlist(parsefile$results$fusionVariants[[i]])))
          }
          FVsData=do.call(rbind,variants)%>%
            mutate(mutation_type="Fusion Variants")%>%
            dplyr::rename(gene5display=gene5Display)%>%
            dplyr::rename(gene3display=gene3Display)
          rm(variants)
        }else{
          #print("No FVs")
        }
        
        #Inherited Relevant Variants
        if (exists("inheritedRelevantVariants",parsefile$results)&&length(parsefile$results$inheritedRelevantVariants)!=0){
          #Extract Data
          if (length(parsefile$results$inheritiedIncidentalFindings)!=0){
          variants=list()
          for(i in 1:length(parsefile$results$inheritedRelevantVariants)){
            variants[[i]]=as.data.frame(t(unlist(parsefile$results$inheritedRelevantVariants[[i]])))
          }
          IRVsData=do.call(rbind,variants)%>%
            mutate(mutation_type="Inherited Relevant Variants")
          rm(variants)
          }else{
            print("No IRVs")
          }
        }else{
          print("No IRVs")
        }
        
        #Inherited Incidental Findings
        if (exists("inheritedIncidentalFindings",parsefile$results)&&length(parsefile$results$inheritedIncidentalFindings)!=0){
          #Extract Data
          if (length(parsefile$results$inheritiedIncidentalFindings)!=0){
          variants=list()
          for(i in 1:length(parsefile$results$inheritedIncidentalFindings)){
            variants[[i]]=as.data.frame(t(unlist(parsefile$results$inheritedIncidentalFindings[[i]])))
          }
          IIFsData=do.call(rbind,variants)%>%
            mutate(mutation_type="Inherited Incidental Findings")
          rm(variants)
          }else{
            print("No IIFs")
          }
        }else{
          print("No IIFs")
        }
        
        #Inherited Variants of Unknown Significance
        if (exists("inheritedVariantsOfUnknownSignificance",parsefile$results)&&length(parsefile$results$inheritedVariantsOfUnknownSignificance)!=0){
          #Extract Data
          if (length(parsefile$results$inheritiedIncidentalFindings)!=0){
          variants=list()
          for(i in 1:length(parsefile$results$inheritedVariantsOfUnknownSignificance)){
            variants[[i]]=as.data.frame(t(unlist(parsefile$results$inheritedVariantsOfUnknownSignificance[[i]])))
          }
          IVUSsData=do.call(rbind,variants)%>%
            mutate(mutation_type="Inherited Variants of Unknown Significance")
          rm(variants)
          }else{
            print("No IVUSs")
          }
        }else{
          print("No IVUSs")
        }
        
        #Merge and Output data tables
        
        if (exists(c("SPAMsData","SBRVsData","SVUSsData","FVsData","IRVsData","IIFsData","IVUSsData"))){
        mergedMutations=rbind.fill(get0("SPAMsData"),get0("SPACNVsData"),get0("SBRVsData"),get0("SVUSsData"),get0("FVsData"),get0("IRVsData"),get0("IIFsData"),get0("IVUSsData"))%>%
          select(mutation_type,everything())
        
        outMutations=merge(patientData,mergedMutations)
        write.csv(outMutations,"~/JSON/mutations.csv",append=TRUE)
        #assign(paste("mergedMutations_",title,sep=''),mergedMutations,envir=.GlobalEnv)
        #assign(paste("patientMutations_",title,sep=''),merge(patientData,mergedMutations),envir=.GlobalEnv)
        }else{
          print("No mutations info")
        }
        
      }else{
        print("No mutations info")
      } 
      
      if (exists(c("orderData","reportData","specimensData","tmbData"))){        outPatients=rbind.fill(get0("patientData"),get0("orderData"),get0("reportData"),get0("specimensData"),get0("tmbData"))        
        write.csv(outPatients,"~/JSON/patients.csv",append=TRUE)        
      }else{
        print("Missing patient info")
      }        
    }  
}
```

Comment: This code is simply too massive for anyone to compose a sensible answer. In your position i would try to debug the code. Carefully read [rstudios guide to debugging](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio) and [chapter 22](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html) in hadley's book [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/). Use this knowledge to find your problem and isolate it, possibly by tracking the value throughout the function. Once you find the problem, and if you can't fix it. Make a smaller example replicating the problem, and post a new question.

Comment: Debugging is an essential skill for anyone who'd like to program, data scientist, analyst and so forth. It is how the vast majority of programming problems are solved in practice.

Comment: Additional notes: even with a reduced function, this is not reproducible since we don't know the files it is operating on when this failure occurs. And your summary of *"it prints `#expected output`"* doesn't help us narrow down where things break, since that string does not occur in your function. I understand (and generally appreciate) the attempt to reduce the size of your question, but (1) the function blew through that recommendation already; and (2) I suggest you provide unambiguous (not necessarily all) context. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem, there were a few files that returned NULL that the code didn't know how to handle and hidden in the thousands of files I had to parse through. This code is for working with health records, so sorry I couldn't post too many specifics! Thanks for the help!